# Session variable set in an included file not in the global $_SESSION array

Tags: php, session

So I have a following code snippet:

first page:

```
<?php
session_start();

var_dump($_SESSION);

function dispatcher($url){
    include "$url.php";
}

dispatcher($_GET['url']);
```

second page:

```
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';
```

The problems is, when I go to secondpage.php and come back to the first page, the $_SESSION array is empty. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have `session_start();` on the second page?

Comment: It's in the top of the first file. The second page is included.

Comment: Make sure session_start(); is at the top of each page and don'

Comment: is `$url` a simple file include (`include "secondpage.php";`) or an actual url include (`include "http://www.xyz.aa/secondpage.php";`) ?

Comment: Yup. it's simple file include based on the $_GET variable.

Comment: `when I go to secondpage.php`: if you mean to open it for itself - it will also need a session_start(); - as Tom Kriek pointed out

Comment: This  `dispatcher($_GET['url']);` is a REALLY bad idea, by the way.

Comment: session_start() does not have to be in every included file I guess. It works with only one session_start() statement- check it.

Comment: Ok. Problem solved. It was caused by my session-destroy function- I forgot to mention about it. Thanks for your responses :)